# R look for specific value in data.frame row by row

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe (maturGI) composed by ntraj lines and 91 columns.
I want to save the position index corresponding to the first time a value of a given row is superior to a threshold (here: 27.66)).

I tried the following scripts

```
    for(i in 1:ntraj) {
    z <- min(which((maturGI[i,]>27.66),arr.ind=TRUE))
    print(z)
  }
```

and

```
    trial <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:x) {
    z <- min(which((maturGI[i,]>27.66),arr.ind=TRUE))
    rbind(z)
  }
  return(data.frame(cbind(z)))
}
```

Yet, it only saved the value corresponding to the very last row instead of the whole sequence. How can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `z` at each iteration. The obvious solution is to make `z` sufficiently big to hold the results before you start looping, *and* assign each result to a different element of `z`. For example

```
z <- numeric(length = ntraj)

for(i in seq_len(ntraj)) {
    z[i] <- min(which(maturGI[i,] > 27.66, arr.ind = TRUE))
}

z
```

Of course, you can do this without looping and hence without having to worry about storage. Also, you can compute the entire set of indices matching your criteria ( > 27.66 ) in a single step. For example, using some dummy data, get the minimum column index for values > 0.25.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10)) ## dummy data
```

You can compute the entire index vector in one go

```
> df > 0.25
         X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

and use that in an `apply()` call. The direct translation of your loop is

```
> apply(df > 0.25, 1, function(x) min(which(x, arr.ind = TRUE)))
 [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 1 2
```

but a simpler solution is to use `which.max()`, noting that `FALSE == 0` and `TRUE == 1` and `which.max` (and its cousin `which.min()`) returns the **first** of any values taking the maximum (or minimum). Hence

```
> apply(df > 0.25, 1, which.max)
 [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 1 2
```

which is pretty succinct...